# React Native Router Flux with Expo SDK 27 child scene undefined prop

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation

I am developing an app with React Native(Expo), and I am using React Native Router Flux for navigation. As you know, Router Flux is a library that builds on react native navigation. I recently updated my expo sdk to 27 from 25 to use React Native 0.55v. The expo sdk 27 needs react-navigation 1.5.11 so I updated it, then I need to update the router flux to 4.0.0-beta.31.

Before the updates, everything works perfectly.. However, now I can not pass props to child scenes in a drawer. You can find the versions below before and after the update.

BEFORE:
expo: 25
react native: 0.52
react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.22"
react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19

AFTER:
expo: 27
react native: 0.55
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.31",
"react-navigation": "^1.5.11"

And, you can find the example of my scene layout below:

```
<Drawer
      hideNavBar
      key="activitiesDrawer"
      contentComponent={ActivitiesDrawer}
      drawerWidth={300}
    >
      <Scene key="activitiesMain" headerTintColor="#fff">
        <Scene
          key="activities"
          component={Activities}
          hideNavBar={true}
          panHandlers={null}
          initial
          title="Activities"
          navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
        >
        </Scene>
    </Scene>
 </Drawer>
```

I am giving a prop to activitiesDrawer, and I can not get that prop from activities. Is this a new bug or this feature is removed. If it is a bug, how can I fix this? Oh and no I am not using redux.